# Highcharts Legend formatting

Tags: highcharts, legend

I have a line chart which includes 3 lines with 3 different names : Apple, Orange, Watermelon. I would like to add text to each of these legends, for example: Apple - 123, Orange - 456, Watermelon - 789. Could anyone help me how can I do that ?

Thank you in advanced !

Comment: Use [`legend.labelFormat`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormat) or [`legend.labelFormatter`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.labelFormatter).

Comment: can you please tell a litte bit more in details. I also tried labelFormatter but it applied the same text for all series, I would like to make seperate text for seperate series

Comment: I got the anser, it used `labelFormatter` and put variables 'customLegendText' for each series, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/wp2e21du/